# Suspecting that some calculus is wrong in my book

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Here is something which I am skeptical that it might be wrong:

$V$ is a two-variable $C^{\infty}$ function such that $V(t,w) = e^{-rt} F(w)$, for some one-variable $C^{\infty}$ function $F$. Let $z = V_w (t,w)$ and define a function $J$ such that 
$$ J(t,z) = V(t,w) - wz.$$

Then it asserts that $J_t = V_t$.

(But I get the following: $$J(t,z) = V(t,w) - w V_w (t,w) = e^{-rt} ( F(w) - wF'(w) ),$$ hence $$J_t= -r e^{-rt} ( F(w) - wF'(w) )   \neq V_t.)$$

Can anyone tell me which is right?

Comment: The problem is that you can't just sub back for $z$. You have to treat it as just a variable when you partial differentiate since your function $J$ is defined in terms of the variables $t$ and $z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the definition of the partial derivative to show that this is true. Explanations for OP's issues are suggested in comments.

$$\begin{align}
J_t(t,z) &= \lim_{\Delta t\rightarrow 0}\frac{J(t+\Delta t,w)-J(t,w)}{\Delta t}\\
&=\lim_{\Delta t\rightarrow 0}\frac{(V(t+\Delta t,w)-wz)-(V(t,z)-wz)}{\Delta t}\\
&=\lim_{\Delta t\rightarrow 0}\frac{V(t+\Delta t,w)-V(t,z)}{\Delta t}\\
&=V_t(t,w)
\end{align}
$$